# Verify if the app is going to background or the fragment will be destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I need to raise a notification when the app starts to run in background, I placed the NotificationManager's notify() method inside a Fragment's onStop() method and the notification is working fine, but when the user go to another activity the onStop() method is also called, and I don't want to notify in that case.

I found 2 answers that can help, but I don't think they are good approaches.

1. Create a flag and set it to true every time a listener that go to another activity is called, if the flag is true simple do not notify when the onStop() method is called.
2. Handle all the actions that can put the application on background (I don't know all of them) and notify only in theses cases.

There is a way to verify if the onStop() has been called because the application is going to background or because the Fragment is going to be destroyed?

Sorry about the bad English

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering this diagram http://staticfree.info/~steve/complete_android_fragment_lifecycle.png seems like there is no way to do this, also your first decision looks ok.

Comment: I'll probably do that, I was just wondering if there is something already provided by the Android API to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform an if statement to check if the user has triggered the onStop() method. I would use the Listeners to make this.

Comment: The first option that I said, right? Using the flag.